# JointsWP Flex Top Bar align-right not working

Tags: zurb-foundation, flexbox, zurb-foundation-6

I'm using JointsWP with Foundation 6 in Flex mode. I'm trying to contain the top bar to the grid, which is working with "row column", but I can't align the top-bar-right to the right for some unknown reason. This is my code:

```
<div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="top-bar-menu" data-hide-for="<?php echo $breakpoint ?>">
    <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle></button>
</div>

<div class="top-bar" id="top-bar-menu">
    <div class="row column">
        <div class="top-bar-left show-for-<?php echo $breakpoint ?>">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="top-bar-right align-right">
            <?php joints_top_nav(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is how it looks:

[image: Top Bar]

How can I make sure that the menu is aligned to the right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Foundation bug (not JointsWP specific) that is going to be addressed in the 6.2.1 release.

https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/8409

Comment: Ah, that clarifies a lot. Thanks!